# what does router.get and router.post do?

Tags: express, mean-stack

Im developing a node application with express.

In my users.js file in the routes folder, i have 3 routes /register, /authenticate, and /profile route. what does router.post do? and what does router.get do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`router.post()` refers to `POST` requests and `router.get()` referes to `GET` request.

The difference between the two is that a GET request, is requesting data from a specified source and a POST request submits data to a specified resource to be processed.

For example when you load a sign up page, that is a GET request as you are requesting data from the server and when you submit that form it's a POST request as your inputted data will be processed and assorted into a database, etc.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me understand it

Answer (score 2):

`router.post()` and `router.get()` refer to POST and GET requests respectively. When your app is sent an HTTP POST request at the specified address, the post method is what will fire. The same for GET.

Comment: I don't know if your trying to be smart but duh i understand that methods will be called. What is the difference between the two?